# Material UI Autcomplete Result Text in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui

I'm using the Material UI's Autocomplete Component and facing an issue where the value is being displayed instead of the text element. I'm using the following format as my datasource:

```
[{value: 'someValue', text: 'My Text'}, {value: 'someOtherValue', text: 'Some other Text'}]
```

When the user enters a query it correctly finds the matching results but the dropdown itself displays the value instead of the text.

**Example**

User searches for "My":

Result:

```
[someValue]
```

What I want:

```
[My Text]
```

It actually seems counterintuitive to me the way it works right now.

> material-ui/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.js [Lines 346-354]

When i change the source code of the component from:

```
requestsList.push({
  text: item.text,
  value: _react2.default.createElement(_MenuItem2.default, {
                  innerDivStyle: styles.innerDiv,
                  primaryText: item.value,
                  disableFocusRipple: disableFocusRipple,
                  key: index
                })
              });
```

to

```
requestsList.push({
  text: item.text,
  value: _react2.default.createElement(_MenuItem2.default, {
                  innerDivStyle: styles.innerDiv,
                  primaryText: item.text,
                  disableFocusRipple: disableFocusRipple,
                  key: index
                })
              });
```

it works as I need it.

I couldn't find any open issue regarding this. Am I simply doing it wrong?

Best
Matt

Comment: that's the way it works.. why dont you just map your datasource into a "valid" one? Example ```{value: 'My Text', text: 'My Text', internalValue: 'someValue'}```

Comment: yeah I could do that - but I wonder whats 'value' and 'text' is suppossed to be used for as Im simply giving them the same value anyway. I could simply use a simple array for that: ['My Text1', 'My Text2'].

Can you give me an example/useCase where {value & text} is used correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically this is the meaning of each property:

**text:** Property that's gonna be displayed in the input once you select one of the options.

**value** Property that's gonna be displayed for each option inside the *popover*. It can be a `text`or a `node`.

I agree with you about the lack of an explanation about these properties in the documentation, but we can see them being used in the examples, mainly in the second section (Data sources). PR's are welcomed..

They have 2 different properties there because many times the user needs to display different values, and most (if not all) of the libraries out there support it. There could be a *default* property that would fill both needs in case one of them has no value but it doesn't so far, you can even suggest it if you want or create a PR.

Hope I could help.

Comment: great explanation. Thanks for clarification!